# richtextbox c# auto show

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

So heres my 1st question,

i have a rich text box control in c#, problem is, i have to scroll down to see the latest stream(im using filesystemwatcher). now, how can i make the richtextbox to display the last line so that i do not have to scroll down. thanks. (in other words, i want richtextbox to show the latest text)

Also 2nd question, how do i create a file using an object and close the stream object. coz i want to overwrite an existing file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
 rtb.SelectionLength = 0;
    rtb.SelectionStart = rtb.Text.Length;
    rtb.ScrollToCaret();
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this could you do for qouestion #1

```
txtBox.ScrollToLine(txtBox.LineCount - 1);
```

now you will always see the last line

edit: 
just saw it's a rich text box. Just do this:

```
txtBox.SelectionLength = 0;
txtBox.SelectionStart = txtBox.Text.Length;
txtBox.ScrollToCaret();
```

if you want to overwrite a file just do this:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\file.txt", FileMode.Create);
```

Comment: theres no scrolltoline property for richtextbox

Comment: txtBox is the name of the richTextBox... I gues you should write `richTextBox1` instead of txtBox...just look for the name of your rich text box